# Download R Package via Github

Tags: r, github, package, devtools

I've been attempting to install the `rethinking` package for R. I've downloaded the prerequisites, including `rstan`, but am still getting the same error message. My code is as follows:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("rmcelreath/rethinking")
```

I keep getting this output:

```
Downloading GitHub repo rmcelreath/rethinking@master
Skipping 1 packages ahead of CRAN: StanHeaders
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\noahj\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK0JHwE\remotes2a60431d781f\rmcelreath-rethinking-f393f30/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'rethinking': (1.6s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (725ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'rethinking_2.00.tar.gz' (699ms)

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/noahj/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rethinking' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'rstan' was built under R version 3.6.3
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rethinking'
* removing 'C:/Users/noahj/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rethinking'
Error: Failed to install 'rethinking' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/noahj/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpK0JHwE/file2a605bda3304/rethinking_2.00.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Thank you to anyone with any insights and help!

Comment: What is your `options("warn")` value? What is your R version number?

Comment: ```options("warn")``` gives 0, and I'm working in 3.6.2

Comment: From the log, something changed a warning to an error to cause it to fail. Is there anything else you might have run before the install to do that?  Normally the message about being built on a different version of R is something that can be safely ignored.

Comment: I have been trying to install it after restarting RStudio, so I cannot think of anything I would be running beforehand.